# calculating data from a database in netbeans

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

I'm writting a program where I need to sort a table in a database and do the following calculation.But I dont get the results for the whole table.I only get the result of the first row of the table.Can some one tell me whats wrong.Is my while loop correct?what should I do to get the calculations for the whole table?

```
    Calendar cal=new GregorianCalendar();
    int c_month=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int c_year=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Are You sure You Want to Start Process?");



    try{

    String sql="Select * from Allowance order by Employee_No,Year,Month DESC";
    int i=0;
    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    bar.setValue(i+5);
    rs=pst.executeQuery();


    do {
        String PreEmpNo=rs.getString("Employee_No");
        int Amt=0;

        do {
            Amt=Amt+rs.getInt("Amount");

            i=i+2;
            bar.setValue(i);
        }while(rs.next() && (PreEmpNo==rs.getString("Employee_No")));
        if(Amt>0){

            String sql1="insert into Payroll values ("+PreEmpNo+","+Amt+")";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
            pst.execute();

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"one data saved");
            bar.setValue(i+5);


        }

        }while(rs.next()&& (c_year==rs.getInt("Year")) && (c_month==rs.getInt("Month")));

    }catch(SQLException | HeadlessException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

Comment: well what is your rs object instantiated as?  Its the object you use to store the pst.executeQuery(); result.

Comment: rs is the result set.When I execute this first row of the table is sent back to the new table in the exact same way

Comment: Have you checked that the resulting query returns the set you want?  Have you tried using a group by clause in your sql statement and iterating through each employee's amounts until a new employee number is visible?